# How to "wait" for a React context provider that takes some time to build the value provided?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a global context in a Next.js application, which takes five seconds compute the value provided:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState(state => ({ ...state, foo: 'bar' })), 5000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={state}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () =>
  useContext(GlobalContext);
```

I use the above `<GlobalContextProvider>` component in my custom `_app.js` (code omitted for brevity). In my homepage, I use the value provided:

```js
import { useGlobalContext } from '../context/global';

export default function Home() {
  const context = useGlobalContext();

  return (
    <div>
      {context.foo}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I "wait" the value provided, showing a "loading indicator"?

Maybe I can `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)` inside the provider and `setIsLoading(true)` when data is ready, but I'm confused if it's the right way to do it (or use something like React.lazy and Suspense).

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways you can do this. You can add a `loading` param to your state that defaults to true.

```js
const { state, setState } = useState({ foo: undefined, loading: true });
```

Then when you set the `foo` value also set `loading` to false. It'll only get set once foo is finished being set.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState(state => ({ ...state, foo: 'bar', loading: false })), 5000);
  }, []);
```

Then inside your render component you pick out both values:

```js
const { foo, loading } = useGlobalContext();

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? <LoadingIcon \> : foo}
    </div>
  );
```

Or you could just check whether foo has been set to anything yet:

```js
const { foo } = useGlobalContext();

  return (
    <div>
      {foo || <LoadingIcon \>}
    </div>
  );
```

The first way is probably better.

Comment: I used this concept and I like it with a slight modification: since it is central state I name my property stateLoading - as to not confuse it on local screens with loading or isLoading.